# ImageReader's onImageAvailable method doesn't call and preview shows only 8 frames in slow motion and freezes (Camera2)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2, xiaomi

I noticed strange behavior on Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro. I tested the application on hundreds of phones but this problem appears only on this device and only when used ImageReader with `YUV_420_888` format and 176*144 preview resolution (for example with 320 * 240 or JPEG or without `ImageReader` as capture surface everything works well). `onImageAvailable` method doesn't call, preview shows only 8 frames in slow motion and freezes, app slows down. `onCaptureCompleted()` in `CameraCurrentParamsReceiver` also calls only 8 times.

I get the smallest resolution by using `getMinPreviewSize` (176 * 144 for this Xiaomi phone).

```
const val PREVIEW_IMAGE_FORMAT = ImageFormat.YUV_420_888
const val IMAGE_READER_MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_IMAGES = 4
val previewCaptureCallback = CameraCurrentParamsReceiver(this)

private fun startPreview(cameraDevice: CameraDevice, cameraProperties: CameraProperties)
{
    val imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(cameraProperties.previewSize.width,
            cameraProperties.previewSize.height,
            PREVIEW_IMAGE_FORMAT,
            IMAGE_READER_MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_IMAGES)

    this.imageReader = imageReader
    bufferedImageConverter = BufferedImageConverter(cameraProperties.previewSize.width, cameraProperties.previewSize.height)

    val previewSurface = previewSurface
    val previewSurfaceForCamera =
            if (previewSurface != null)
            {
                if (previewSurface.isValid)
                {
                    previewSurface
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Invalid preview surface - camera preview display is not available")
                    null
                }
            }
            else
            {
                null
            }

    val captureSurfaces = listOfNotNull(imageReader.surface, previewSurfaceForCamera)

    cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(
            captureSurfaces,
            object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback()
            {
                override fun onConfigureFailed(cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onConfigureFailed() cannot configure camera")
                    if (isCameraOpened(cameraDevice))
                    {
                        shutDown("onConfigureFailed")
                    }
                }

                override fun onConfigured(cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onConfigured()")

                    if (!isCameraOpened(cameraDevice))
                    {
                        cameraCaptureSession.close()
                        shutDown("onConfigured.isCameraOpened")

                        return
                    }

                    captureSession = cameraCaptureSession
                    try
                    {
                        val request = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
                        captureSurfaces.forEach { request.addTarget(it) }
                        CameraPreviewRequestInitializer.initializePreviewRequest(request, cameraProperties, controlParams, isControlParamsStrict)
                        captureRequestBuilder = request

                        val previewCallback = PreviewFrameHandler(this@Camera2)
                        this@Camera2.previewFrameHandler = previewCallback
                        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(previewCallback, previewCallback.backgroundHandler)
                        
                        cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(request.build(), previewCaptureCallback, null)
                    }
                    catch (ex: CameraAccessException)
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onConfigured() failed with exception", ex)

                        shutDown("onConfigured.CameraAccessException")
                    }
                }
            },
            null)
}

private fun chooseCamera(manager: CameraManager): CameraProperties?
{
    val cameraIdList = manager.cameraIdList
    if (cameraIdList.isEmpty())
    {
        return null
    }

    for (cameraId in cameraIdList)
    {
        val characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId)
        val facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING)
        if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK)
        {
            val minPreviewSize = getMinPreviewSize(characteristics)
            if (minPreviewSize == null)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "chooseCamera() Cannot determine the preview size")

                return null
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "chooseCamera() chosen camera id: $cameraId, preview size: $minPreviewSize")

            return CameraProperties(cameraId,
                    minPreviewSize,
                    characteristics)
        }
    }

    return null
}

private fun getMinPreviewSize(characteristics: CameraCharacteristics): Size?
{
    val map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP)
    if (map == null)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "getMinPreviewSize() Map is empty")

        return null
    }

    return map.getOutputSizes(Constants.Camera.PREVIEW_IMAGE_FORMAT)?.minBy { it.width * it.height }
}
```

`PreviewFrameHandler` and `CameraCurrentParamsReceiver` (`previewCaptureCallback` variable)

```
private class PreviewFrameHandler(private val parent: Camera2) : ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener, Handler.Callback
{
    val backgroundHandler: Handler
    private val backgroundHandlerThread: HandlerThread = HandlerThread("Camera2.PreviewFrame.HandlerThread")
    private val mainHandler: Handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), this)

    /**
     * Main thread.
     */

    init
    {
        backgroundHandlerThread.start()
        backgroundHandler = Handler(backgroundHandlerThread.looper)
    }

    fun shutDown()
    {
        backgroundHandlerThread.quit()
        mainHandler.removeMessages(0)
    }

    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message?): Boolean
    {
        msg ?: return false

        parent.cameraFrameListener.onFrame(msg.obj as RGBImage)

        return true
    }

    /**
     * Background thread.
     */

    private val relativeTimestamp = RelativeTimestamp()

    override fun onImageAvailable(reader: ImageReader)
    {
        var image: Image? = null
        try
        {
            image = reader.acquireNextImage()
            image ?: return

            val rgbImage = parent.bufferedImageConverter?.convertYUV420spToRGB(image, relativeTimestamp.updateAndGetSeconds(image.timestamp))
            rgbImage ?: return

            mainHandler.sendMessage(mainHandler.obtainMessage(0, rgbImage))
        }
        catch (ex: Exception)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onImageAvailable()", ex)
        }
        finally
        {
            image?.close()
        }
    }

    private class RelativeTimestamp
    {
        private var initialNanos = 0L

        fun updateAndGetSeconds(currentNanos: Long): Double
        {
            if (initialNanos == 0L)
            {
                initialNanos = currentNanos
            }

            return nanosToSeconds(currentNanos - initialNanos)
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Class used to read current camera params.
 */
private class CameraCurrentParamsReceiver(private val parent: Camera2) : CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback()
{
    private var isExposureTimeExceptionLogged = false
    private var isIsoExceptionLogged = false

    override fun onCaptureSequenceAborted(session: CameraCaptureSession, sequenceId: Int)
    {
    }

    override fun onCaptureCompleted(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, result: TotalCaptureResult)
    {
        try
        {
            val exposureTimeNanos = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME)
            if (exposureTimeNanos != null)
            {
                parent.currentExposureTimeNanos = exposureTimeNanos
            }
        }
        catch (ex: IllegalArgumentException)
        {
            if (!isExposureTimeExceptionLogged)
            {
                isExposureTimeExceptionLogged = true
            }
        }

        try
        {
            val iso = result.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY)
            if (iso != null)
            {
                parent.currentIso = iso
            }
        }
        catch (ex: IllegalArgumentException)
        {
            if (!isIsoExceptionLogged)
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "Cannot get current SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, exception: " + ex.message)
                isIsoExceptionLogged = true
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCaptureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, failure: CaptureFailure)
    {
    }

    override fun onCaptureSequenceCompleted(session: CameraCaptureSession, sequenceId: Int, frameNumber: Long)
    {
    }

    override fun onCaptureStarted(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, timestamp: Long, frameNumber: Long)
    {
    }

    override fun onCaptureProgressed(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, partialResult: CaptureResult)
    {
    }

    override fun onCaptureBufferLost(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, target: Surface, frameNumber: Long)
    {
    }
}
```

As I understand something is wrong with preview size but I cannot find correct way how to get this value and the strangest thing is that this problem appears only on this Xiaomi device. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

176x144 is sometimes a problematic resolution for devices.  It's really only listed by camera devices because it's sometimes required for recording videos for MMS (multimedia text message) messages.  These videos, frankly, look awful, but it's still frequently a requirement by cellular carriers that they work.

But on modern devices with 12 - 50 MP cameras, the camera hardware actually struggles to scale images down to 176x144 from the sensor full resolution (> 20x downscale!), so sometimes certain combinations of sizes can cause problems.

I'd generally recommend not using preview resolutions below 320x240, to minimize issues, and definitely not mix a 176x144 preview with a high-resolution still capture.